# Books on Buddhism for Beginners

Tags: academic-buddhism, secular-buddhism, western-buddhism, general-buddhism

I'm just starting the study of Buddhism and I'm really interested in the whole philosophy of Buddhism. Can someone please suggest some books for beginners ? Thank you.

Comment: I also found these helpful -- [English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4109/254) and [Chronological or other sequence for beginners](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/254) -- to also be able to read more details, rather than only being given an overview. There are several branches (philosophies?) of Buddhism, I think most see the "suttas" (or their Chinese versions) as fundamental or basic. Later (Mahayana) doctrine may be easier to understand after you've been acquainted with the basic doctrine (or Mahayana may be stand-alone too).

Comment: Some of the "introduction to Mahayana" questions that I've asked include [Pāramitāyāna and Tantrayāna](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13703/254), and [Spontaneity in Zen](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/26338/254), and [this (about non-duality)](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/28504/254), and [Describe the Mahayana path](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/28505/254).

Comment: See also [Introductory books to Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/60/254) for other book recommendation (maybe this duplicates and should be merged with the [Recommendation - Book for beginner](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/12794/recommendation-book-for-beginner) topic); and [List of book recommendations](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25889/254).